# How to automate sign in Expo React Native app

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

Got a question: Just came back to one of my old Expo apps that would sign people in even when the app is refreshed using the user state. For some reason, it doesn't work anymore. The code is supposed to read the user object, which is usually not null, and check if the email is verified, which will then sign in the user without the user trying to log in. The problem I found is that the user object is null, which doesn't automatically sign in the user. Really, the first line that doesn't work is the start of the unsubscribe variable. Can someone help with what I got for automatically signing people in. Note: I am using the Firebase package to automate this

Code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setTheme("dark");

    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      console.log(user);

      if (user !== null) {
        if (user.emailVerified) {
          console.log(user);

          console.log(user.emailVerified);
          navigation.replace("Home");
        }
      }
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
```

Comment: "For some reason, it doesn't work anymore." This is hard to help with. What does the code do, and what did you expect it to do? Is there an error message? Also: did you debug the code locally already? If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Sorry for my hard to understand description. The code is supposed to read the user object, which is usually not null, and check if the email is verified, which will then sign in the user without the user trying to log in. The problem I found is that the user object is null, which doesn't automatically sign in the user. Really, the first line that doesn't work is the start of the unsubscribe variable.

Comment: Are your credentials still valid?

Comment: devpolo likely has the gist of it. When did the user sign-in and with what provider? Are those credentials still valid, and didn't they expire?

Comment: The user signs via email and password. The test user I am using can still sign in, but can't happen automatically.

Comment: You have an idea as to what is possibly going on?

Comment: Still looking for a solution.